# Loop through all files in subfolders

Tags: matlab, for-loop, subdirectory, cd

I need to loop through each file that are in the following subfolders:

```
/Testing
/Training
/Validation
```

This would be similar to the code below except it would loop through every file in those three subfolders (right now it loops through files 1 to 92, but now they are split up into these thry folders).

```
for i=1:92
str = sprintf('load data%i.mat', i);
eval(str);
Info.data=Info.data(:,[1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11]);
str = sprintf('save data%i.mat', i);
eval(str);
end
```

Comment: See [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html). Note that there is no recursion so you will need to look for an external tool or make your own. You could also use a [Windows system call](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35605760/2748311). Also, there's no need to use `eval` here. `save(str)` works just fine.

Comment: in the future you should just edit your original question. re-posting the same question multiple times isn't kosher. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657019/creating-a-model-matrix-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

```
p1=pwd;
p2={'\Testing' '\Training' '\Validation'};
for i=1:length(p2)
    cd([p1, p2{i}]) 
    files = dir('*.mat');
    for file = files'
        load(file.name);
        Info.data=Info.data(:,[9,10,11]);
        save(file.name);
    cd(p1);
end
end
```